# extracting data from sns.kdeplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is it possible to extract the data from a `sns.kdeplot()` before plotting?
ie. without using the function
`y.get_lines()[0].get_data()` post plotting

Comment: extract what data?  you need some data to start with in order to generate the plot.  please post some code so we have something to go with.

Comment: `density_data = np.repeat(df.loc[:,"Position"].values.tolist(), df.loc[:,"BaseCount"].values)` `sns.kdeplot(density_data)` This obviously generates density data which is automatically plotted. Is it possible to extract this data

Comment: You should use the scipy or statsmodels KDE functions.

Comment: Both of these functions output an object. Still can't figure out how to extract actual density values.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you are able to do that. These functions are not designed for this. Now you got two ways of achieving your goal: mimic the calculation in statsmodels/scipy (look at seaborn's sources) or calculate it yourself (again: scipy, statsmodels or even scikit-learn) + plot it yourself without seaborn.

Comment: Thanks! Finally got it right with statsmodel using .density attribute

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by extracting the line data from the matplotlib Axes object:

```
import numpy as np
from seaborn import kdeplot

my_data = np.random.randn(1000)
my_kde = kdeplot(my_data)
line = my_kde.lines[0]
x, y = line.get_data()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x[x>0], y[x>0])
```

alternatively the statsmodels way:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

dens = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(np.random.randn(1000))
dens.fit()
x =np.linspace(0,1,100) #restrict range to (0,1)
y = dens.evaluate(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [statsmodels's documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/kernel_density.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate bimodal disrtibution
X1 = np.random.normal(100, 10, 250)
X2 = np.random.normal(10, 20, 250)
X = np.concatenate([X1, X2])

# get density from seaborn
x, y = sns.kdeplot(X).lines[0].get_data()

# get density from statsmodel
kde = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(X).fit()
xx, yy = (kde.support, kde.density)

# compare outputs
plt.plot(x, y, label='from sns')
plt.plot(xx, yy, label='from statsmodels')
plt.legend()
```

[image]